# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

I've some issues with my as codes as shown below, whenever my item hits the camera, it will pop up :

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference. at Prototype1/hitCamera1()
>
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference. at Prototype1/hitCamera2()
>
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference. at Prototype1/hitCamera3()

Update #1: i've realised the error lies with the "channel3.stop();" code on every hit camera. Why is there error on it?

```
stop();
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;

import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

var leftArrow:Boolean = false;
var rightArrow:Boolean = false;
var upArrow:Boolean = false;
var downArrow:Boolean = false;
var Test_hitting:Boolean = false;

var backSound2:VolatileReaction =  new VolatileReaction();
var channel3:SoundChannel = backSound2.play();


stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown);
stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyup);
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressedUp);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlayer);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitCamera1);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitCamera2);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitCamera3);

function keyPressedDown(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
if(event.keyCode == 37)
{
    leftArrow = true;
}else if (event.keyCode == 39)
{
    rightArrow = true;
}else if(event.keyCode == 38)
{
    upArrow = true;
   }else if (event.keyCode == 40)
{
    downArrow = true;
}
}

function keyPressedUp (event:KeyboardEvent)
{
if(event.keyCode == 37)
{
    leftArrow = false;
}else if (event.keyCode == 39)
{
    rightArrow = false;
}else if (event.keyCode == 38)
{
    upArrow = false;
}else if(event.keyCode == 40)
{
    downArrow =false;
}
}

 function hitCamera1(event:Event)
 {
 if(camera1.cameralight.hitTestPoint(Player.x - Player.width/2, Player.y - Player.width/2, true))
 {
     channel3.stop();
             gotoAndStop("gameover");

 }
 }

 function hitCamera2(event:Event)
  {
 if(camera2.cameralight.hitTestPoint(Player.x - Player.width/2, Player.y - Player.width/2, true))

 {
    channel3.stop();
     gotoAndStop("gameover");
 }
}

 function hitCamera3(event:Event)
{
if(camera3.cameralight.hitTestPoint(Player.x - Player.width/2, Player.y - Player.width/2, true))

 {
    channel3.stop();
     gotoAndStop("gameover");
 }
 }


 function movePlayer(event:Event)
{
var speed:Number = 3;

if(leftArrow)
{
    Player.x -=speed;
    if(Player.hitTestObject(wall1) || Player.hitTestObject(mainwallLeft)|| Player.hitTestObject(wall2) || Player.hitTestObject(wall3))
    {
        Player.x +=speed;

    }
    if(Player.hitTestObject(exit))
       {
           channel3.stop();
           gotoAndStop("secondStage");
       }


}
if(rightArrow)
{
    Player.x += speed;
    if(Player.hitTestObject(wall1) || Player.hitTestObject(mainwallRight)|| Player.hitTestObject(wall2) || Player.hitTestObject(wall3))
    {
        Player.x -=speed;
    }
    if(Player.hitTestObject(exit))
       {
          channel3.stop();
           gotoAndStop("secondStage");
       }


}
if(upArrow)
{
    Player.y -= speed;
    if(Player.hitTestObject(wall1) || Player.hitTestObject(mainwallUp)|| Player.hitTestObject(wall2) || Player.hitTestObject(wall3))
    {
        Player.y += speed;
    }
    if(Player.hitTestObject(exit))
       {
          channel3.stop();
           gotoAndStop("secondStage");
       }


}
if(downArrow)
{
    Player.y +=speed;
    if(Player.hitTestObject(wall1) || Player.hitTestObject(mainwallDown) || Player.hitTestObject(wall2) || Player.hitTestObject(wall3))
    {
        Player.y-=speed;
    }
    if(Player.hitTestObject(exit))
       {
         channel3.stop();
           gotoAndStop("secondStage");
       }

}


 }
```

Comment: That error is fired when an object is `null` because it does not exist or has another name ! so try to verify your cameras and their lights ...

Answer (score 0):

Because you call HitCamera function on EnterFrame, it may be that "channel3" is null.

try this for HitCamera1, 2 and 3

```
// instead of 
channel3.stop();

// use
if( channel3 ) channel3.stop();
```

Comment: When i put in if( channel3 ) channel3.stop(); , it still shows null for this line.

Comment: If the channel3 is null.... it will keep being null. it is just that you avoid calling method stop() on a null object. therefore you will not receive any runtime error.